# SQL Configuration : Pros & Cons

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am in the midst of evaluating default SQL Server 2008 R2 configuration settings. 
I have been asked to run the below script on the production server:

```
sp_configure 'remote query timeout', 0
sp_configure 'max server memory (MB)', 28000
sp_configure 'remote login timeout', 300
go
reconfigure with override
go
```

Before proceeding on this, I have been trying to gauge the advantages and disadvantages of each line of SQL code.

***Edited on 17-May-2016 14:19 IST***:

Few Microsoft links that I have referred are as below:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms175136.aspx

***Edited on 23-May-2016 11:15 IST***:

I have set the 'MAX SERVER MEMORY' based on feedback here and further investigation from my end. I have provided my inferences to the customer.
I have also provided my inferences on the other 2 queries based on views and answers provided here. 
Thanks to all for your help. I will update this question after inputs from the customer.

Comment: Don't run anything on a production server unless you've run it on a test server and confirmed what the consequences would be. Practice and research before even going near your live server.

Comment: have you tried the query in your server ?

Comment: @utility - I have tried the query on the local system. I have not noticed anything conclusive.

Comment: @RichBenner - I have not run in on the production server. I would heed your advice on the same. Thanks. :)

Comment: Setting MAX MEMORY is always a good idea because SQL Server is greedy and will not release memory just because some other resource is asking for it. Whether it's the right value you're setting however, that depends fully on the server resources and usage. The time out factors - well ..... if usage and measurement has shown changing them will help your setup, then fine. If it's just some arbitrary values given, then ask for more information from the one who gave them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Query will set the query timeout to 0 , i.e No timeout

```
sp_configure 'remote query timeout', 0
```

[image]

> This value has no effect on queries received by the Database Engine.
>   To disable the time-out, set the value to 0. A query will wait until
>   it is canceled.

```
sp_configure 'max server memory (MB)', 28000
```

> amount of memory (in megabytes) that is managed by the SQL Server
>   Memory Manager for a SQL Server process used by an instance of SQL
>   Server.

```
sp_configure 'remote login timeout', 300
```

If you have applications that connect remotely to server ,we can set timeout using the above query.

**Note :**

You can also set the server properties via SSMS (management studio) where you can set the maximum and minimum values rather using the codes as shown in your post.

[image]

**You can very well try these queries ,but settings that you would like to opt in would depend on hardware and application type you are working on.**

Answer (score 0):

I would generally say that these statements are quite idiotic. Yes, seriously.

Line by line:

> sp_configure 'remote query timeout', 0

Makes queries run unlimited time before aborting. While I accept there are long running queries, those should be rare (the default timeout of IIRC 30 seconds handles 99.99% of the queries) and the application programmer can set an appropriate timeout in the rare cases he needs it for this particular query.

> sp_configure 'max server memory (MB)', 28000

Sets max server memory to 28gb. Well, that is nonsense - the DBA should have set that upon install to a sensible value, so it is not needed unless the dba is incompetent. Whether the roughly 28gb make sense I can not comment.

> sp_configure 'remote login timeout', 300

Timeout for remote login 300 seconds. Default of 30 seconds already is plenty. I have serious problems considering a scenario where the server is healthy and does not process logins within less than a handful of seconds.

The only scenario I have seen where this whole batch would make sense is a server dying from overload - which is MOST OFTEN based on some brutal incompetence somewhere. Either the admin (64gb RAM machine configured to only use 2gb for SQL Server for example) or most often the programmers (no indices, ridiculous bad SQL making the server die from overload). Been there, seen that way too often.

Otherwise the timeouts really make little sense.

Comment: Many companies run without a specialized DBA; Also if you use hosting companies then they'll often not have a DBA but just set up basic; Also if your customer/client is self-hosting, they might not have a DBA ..... so "DBA is incompetent" if the value isn't set; well - there are a myriad of reasons for how it can be as it is.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen - Currently, default settings for SQL Server are being used. I have received this script as suggested/probable changes. No DBA is present.

Comment: Strong language.... but regardless you need to provide way more info. With regards to memory: 1. How RAM does the server have? 2. Is the server only running SQL Server or is it running other things?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid
1. Typically, RAM would range 32GB or higher. 
2. I am not to clear on what is meant here by 'other things'.

Comment: If you can only provide a 'typical' RAM figure then it is impossible to provide a 'solid' recommendation for RAM. By 'other things' I mean are you also running IIS or Active directory or Sharepoint or anything else on the server? A basic starting point for Max SQL Server RAM would be Total RAM - RAM required for other services - RAM required for OS. If there are no other services then that might boil down to: 32Gb *(Total RAM)* - 0Gb *(RAM required for other services)* - 4GB *(RAM required for OS)* = 28Gb

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - I have provided a typical RAM figure as my question is generic to multiple servers. There may be servers which have a higher/lower RAM.
Secondly, there is IIS7.5 running on most servers and some other softwares like WireShark, application-specific software. there are some customer-specific software run on the server. I would not be able to share information on all the software present.

Comment: Specifically this: `sp_configure 'max server memory (MB)', 28000`. On a server with 32Gb of RAM that only runs SQL Server this probably makes sense. On a server with 32Gb of RAM that runs IIS this makes no sense. There's no such thing as a (optimal) generic SQL Server configuration

Answer (score 0):

"Remote query timeout" sets how much time before a remote query times out.
"Remote login timeout" set how much time before a login attempt time out.

The values set here could make sense in certain conditions (slow, high-latency network, for example).

"Max server memory" is different. It's a very useful setting, and it should be set almost always to avoid possible performance problems. What value, it depends how much memory is on the server as whole and which other applications/service are running on it. If it's a dedicated server with 32 GB of memory, this value sounds about right.

None of these could be really tested on the test environment, I'm afraid, unless you have an 1:1 replica of the prod environment.

Comment: Agree with you on the inability to test. We do not have a replica of the production environment.

Comment: You should at least know how much RAM the production server has and whether or not it is only running SQL Server. At the very least this is important info. It's like asking "how big should my suitcase be?" Who knows? How long are you staying, what are you doing, is it cold or hot?